# Importing modules in Typescript vs NodeJs

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm creating a Discord bot with Discord.js and Typescript (I'm new to Typescript) and was making a command handler. If I were using NodeJs, this is what I would do:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'))

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./src/commands/${file}`)
    commands.set(command.name, command)
}
```

but I'm wondering what to do for Typescript. I tried doing this:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'))

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    import(`./src/commands/${file}`).then(command => {
        commands.set(command.name, command)
    })
}
```

but I end up with the same error: `Error: Cannot find module './src/commands/pet.ts'`. I know that its not a problem with the directory. Here is the code in `pet.ts`:

```
export default {
    name: 'pet',
    description: 'description',
    async execute({ interaction }) {
        // doing stuff
    }
}
```

If this helps, here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Don’t edit in that you solved it. You *can* however post how you solved it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.ts'))
    
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = ( import(`./src/commands/${file}`) ).default
        commands.set(command.name, command)
        })
    }
```

See if this works